# How can I get the text of a selected item from a Knockout Observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can see all the Knockout-ish ways provided for getting the textual value of a selected item but ONLY if it is generated with either or both:

1. no value attribute
2. Or you provide the array for the "options"

However, I am not loading the options array myself, I am simply trying to observe the selected item in a drop down list and check for the textual representation.  Unfortunately, it this situation, the value returned is always the "value" attribute on a selected item.

I have to do something like the following on an observable:

```
this.selectedText = $("#myId: option:selected).text();
```

I am sure there is a way I can get it sticking with Knockout.

I just want to get the textual value of a selected item where I didn't provide the array of the selection list and the selection list retains value attributes.

```
  <option value="2129">SomeText</option>
```

**EDIT**

To add more concrete understanding of why I want to do that is - the value for the selection item is an ID - I need to be able to trigger a section of code to be visible if a certain selection is made.  Unfortunately, I can't bind to the id of the selection (value) as it might not be the same for development, but the text will always be the same.

Comment: This doesn't work for a reason: The items in that list are data and therefore belong in the view model (or should there be fetched from the model, if necessary), not the view.

Comment: I would contend that "special" values in code should be the same across environments. When I build systems, any value that I use in code as a part of logical determinations is stored in a constant and is consistent across all environments.

Comment: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562631/get-selected-option-text-in-knockout)

Answer (score -2):

I think we have to bind to observable array to make drop down list obserevable documentation at knockout also does not list something else

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html