# get selected option text in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs to bind a select list. Here is a [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LHjBq/)
, I want to get selected option text instead of selected value.

How to get it using knockoutjs ?

```
<select id="projectMenu" name="projectMenu" data-bind="   
        value: selectedProject,
        options:        projectFilters,
        optionsText:    'a', 
        optionsValue:   'b',   
        optionsCaption: '-- Select Project --'
    ">
    </select>
<b>Selected Project:</b> <span data-bind="text: selectedProject"></span>
```

Comment: please provide a code example, not simply a link.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112435/how-can-i-get-the-text-of-a-selected-item-from-a-knockout-observable

Comment: if duplicate then what?? that question never been answered, does it mean no body can ever ask?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to do it is to remove the optionsValue binding.
When you don't sepcify the optionsValue binding, the entire item will be the selected value.

```
<select id="projectMenu" name="projectMenu" data-bind="   
        value: selectedProject,
        options:        projectFilters,
        optionsText:    'a',         
        optionsCaption: '-- Select Project --'
    ">
    </select>
<b>Selected Project:
<span data-bind="text: selectedProject() ? selectedProject().a : 'no selection '"></span>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LHjBq/6/)

Comment: It is working for the subscribe event not for the change event.anyway good solution mate. appreciate your work.by the way fiddle is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

As far I am concerned it is not possible with just a simple binding. But You can easily create computedObservable which choose optionText based on optionValue

```
vm.selectedOption= ko.computed(function () { 
   for (var i = 0; i < this.projectFilters().length; i += 1) {
       var data = this.projectFilters()[i];
       if (data.a === this.selectedProject()) {
           return data.b;
       }
   }
   return null;
}, vm);
```

Comment: I can't do that because i dont want to iterate a big collection, and i have many select list in my view. so it will reduce performance.

Comment: @MotaChuha Unless there are very big collections that should work OK - modern PCs are rather fast ;). And i would advice making performance tests before rejecting this solution - maybe a bit slower performance would be acceptable. If not You should probably write custom knockout binding to achieve requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
vm.selectedCountryName = ko.computed(function () {
        var text = '';
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.countries(), function (item) {
            if (item.CountryId == vm.selectedCountry()) {
                text = item.CountryName;
                return;
            }
        });
        return text;
    });
```