# Get dropdown text using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a dropdown like this:

```
                <select data-bind="options: movieInitValues,
                    optionsText: 'Text',
                    optionsValue: 'Value',
                    value: movieSelectedValue" id="movieSelectDDL"></select>
```

Everything works, however I would like to capture the text of the dropdown into "movieSelectedName" property of the model so that I can display a nice message to the user later. Is there a knockout way of doing this?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Cant you just find the associated text to your selected value in `movieInitValues`?

Comment: Yes, I think that may work, but I was hoping for a knockout way of doing this. I'll use this as a last resort.

Comment: Also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562631/get-selected-option-text-in-knockout

Comment: Explanation for downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem can be solved using custom binding handler:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.readSelectedText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        $(element).change(function () {
            value($("option:selected", this).text());
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    }
};


var vm = {
    movieInitValues: [ {Text: 'Option 1', Value: '1' }, {Text: 'Option 2', Value: '2' }],
    movieSelectedValue: ko.observable(),
    movieSelectedText: ko.observable(),
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: movieInitValues,
                    optionsText: 'Text',
                    optionsValue: 'Value',
                    readSelectedText: movieSelectedText,
                    value: movieSelectedValue" id="movieSelectDDL"></select>

<div>
    Text: <span data-bind='text: movieSelectedText'></span>
</div>
<div>
    Value: <span data-bind='text: movieSelectedValue'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, this required the least change to my Model to work.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your code, it looks like the values in `movieInitValues` have a `Text` property and a `Value` property.  You've told knockout to use the `Value` property as the value to store in `movieSelectedValue` through the use of `optionsValue: 'Value'`.

If you need both the `Text` and the `Value` properties for use elsewhere, it's best to let knockout store the *actual object* selected in your observable, then use the properties elsewhere.  If you remove the `optionsValue` setting, it will store the object:

```
<select data-bind="options: movieInitValues,
    optionsText: 'Text',
    value: movieSelected" id="movieSelectDDL"></select>
```

You can then create two computed observables on your VM, based on the updated `movieSelected` observable I just created:

```
vm.movieSelected = ko.observable();
vm.movieSelectedValue = ko.computed(function() { return vm.movieSelected().Value; } );
vm.movieSelectedText = ko.computed(function() { return vm.movieSelected().Text; });
```

or just update your other bindings to directly use `vm.movieSelected().Text` and `vm.movieSelected().Value`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would fix this problem but create another problem. I need both "value" - so I can do other ajax calls based on this, and I need "text" for UI purposes.

Comment: @ThufirHawat Right, in that case you'll need something a bit different - I will update

Comment: @ThufirHawat Updated - it will now put the actual object that's behind the selected value in the observable - you then have access to all the properties etc on it.