# Get value from select in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a `select` element bound using ko and it's displaying data perfectly.

```html
<select name="assetTypeID" 
        class="form-control" 
        id="assetTypeID" 
        data-bind="options: $root.personalassettype_dd, 
                   optionsValue: 'id', 
                   optionsText: 'text', 
                   optionsIncludeDestroyed: true,
                   value:typeid">
</select>
```

I want to show the selected value of this dropdown in a span. What I am trying is:

```html
<span id="spnassetTypeID" data-bind="text: $root.personalassettype_dd.text"></span>
```

Have gone through [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562631/get-selected-option-text-in-knockout) but that didn't work, any ideas?

I'm very close to the answer now. If I write:

```html
<span id="spnassetTypeID" data-bind="text: $root.personalassettype_dd()[0].text"></span>
```

it works for me at displays the value of the item at 0th index as it is harcoded.

But when I try writing this:

```html
<span id="spnassetTypeID" data-bind="text: $root.personalassettype_dd()[typeid].text"></span>
```

It gives me this error:

> Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: TypeError: Unable to get property 'text' of undefined or null reference;
>   Bindings value: text: $root.personalassettype_dd()[typeid].....

So it means that somehow it's not getting '`typeid`' when I was it in place of array index.

Note: I also tried passing typeid in quotes, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38651148/419956) yet? It's the proper solution IMO. You might get that second approach to work if you try real hard, but it means you're fighting KO, not using it to the best of your advantage.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. It also removes the 'values' from the options, which I need for some other functionality

Comment: Then it would help to change your question's code into a [mcve] that's representative of your situation. Unless you tell us, we can't know what you need, and *as far as the current code* is concerned @Adrian's answer is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link of the post you gave has a correct answer.

Your text binding in `spnassetTypeID` should have the value of the value in your `select` element.
And also, remove your `optionsValue` binding.

The use of `optionsValue` is for knockout to determine which property of the object (item from your `personalassettype_dd`) will be used. For example, if I changed the `optionsValue` to `text` then the value of `typeId` will be the `text` of the selected object. If I removed the `optionsValue` then the whole selected object will be the value of `typeId`.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdkfdkgd/) for a minimal example using your markup.

```
<select name="assetTypeID" class="form-control" id="assetTypeID" data-bind="options: $root.personalassettype_dd, optionsText: 'text', optionsIncludeDestroyed: true,value:typeid"></select>
<span id="spnassetTypeID" data-bind="text: $root.typeid().text"></span>
```

Comment: What didn't work from it?
Though if you want to continue with your approach from the update, the problem lies with the `typeid` not initialized with a value beforehand I guess. `this.typeid = ko.observable(0)` so that it will have the first value of the dropdown initially.